# Show only items that has no default category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that have this structure.

```
ItemNumber | Category | DefaultCategory
---------------------------------------
1234 | Category 1 | 0
1234 | Category 2 | 1
1234 | Category 3 | 0
ABCD | Category 1 | 0
ABCD | Category 2 | 0
YZYX | Category 2 | 0
YZYX | Category 1 | 0
```

I need to get all items that has no default category. So in this example i have to get
ABCD and YZYX

Can anyone help me, to how my SQL should be?
This is my best try, but that's not correct.

```
SELECT [ItemNumber] FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] WHERE DefaultCategory = 0 GROUP BY ItemNumber
```

Comment: The word Navision and the syntax indicates that you are using ms sql server, and not MySQL.

Comment: Look into `not exists`, or `not in` or how to use self-joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple not in as below

```
SELECT distinct [ItemNumber] FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] 
    Where ItemNumber not in ( Select ItemNumber from [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] where DefaultCategory = 1 )
```

Comment: Welcome have fun

Answer (score 1):

You have not aggregation function so you should use distinct  (an not use improperly group by)

then you can use a not in clasue an subselect

```
  SELECT distinct ItemNumber 
  FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] 
  WHERE ItemNumber not in (
    select ItemNumber 
    FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] 
    where DefaultCategory <> 0
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [ItemNumber] FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Danmark$eShopInventCategory] WHERE ItemNumber not in (select ItemNumber where DefaultCategory = 1) group by ItemNumber
```